# How load() works in EAV model in Magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

> $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId());

load() will go Mage_Core_Model_Abstract inside load() function,

```
public function load($id, $field=null)
{
    $this->_beforeLoad($id, $field);
    $this->_getResource()->load($this, $id, $field);
    $this->_afterLoad();
    $this->setOrigData();
    $this->_hasDataChanges = false;
    return $this;
}
```

Now this should go to abstract class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract where load process is defined:

```
public function load($object, $entityId, $attributes = array())
    {
        Varien_Profiler::start('__EAV_LOAD_MODEL__');
        /**
         * Load object base row data
         */
        $select  = $this->_getLoadRowSelect($object, $entityId);
        $row     = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchRow($select);

        ...

        if (empty($attributes)) {
            $this->loadAllAttributes($object);
        } else {
            foreach ($attributes as $attrCode) {
                $this->getAttribute($attrCode);
            }
        }

        $this->_loadModelAttributes($object);

        ...
    }
```

But I can't understand how

```
$this->_getResource()->load($this, $id, $field); in Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
```

connects to abstract class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract???

Because `load($this, $id, $field)` is going to `abstract class Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract` :

```
public function load(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object, $value, $field = null)
{
    if (is_null($field)) {
        $field = $this->getIdFieldName();
    }

    $read = $this->_getReadAdapter();
    if ($read && !is_null($value)) {
        $select = $this->_getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object);
        $data = $read->fetchRow($select);

        if ($data) {
            $object->setData($data);
        }
    }

    $this->unserializeFields($object);
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the _construct method in the product model (catalog/product). This method is triggered when one creates an object. It shows which resource model to use:

```
$this->_init('catalog/product');
```

Next, in the Mage_Core_Model_Abstract in the load method, there is an expression $this->_getResource(). It can bring back the object of the class
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product (which, in turn, is inherited from Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract).

Basically, every model can have its own resource model with its own class.

Comment: Thnx a lot..I got the concept.. :)